# Default values are submitting as null in React Js

Tags: reactjs, null, default-value, onsubmit, form-control

```
export const EmailAddress = () => {
 const userInfo = 'aaaa@gmail.com';
 return (
   <FormControl id="email-address" model="attestation.emailAddress" required>
     {(inputProps, errorProps) => (
       <React.Fragment>
         <Label>Email address</Label>
         <TextInput
           type="email"
           data-testid="attestation-email-address"
           name="emailAddress"
           value={userInfo}
           defaultValue={userInfo}
         />
       </React.Fragment>
     )}
   </FormControl>
 );
};
```

in FormControl TextInput i set defaultValue and value but after submit its is considering as null in output

Comment: What are using that default value for?

Comment: to set and display email value in non editable textinput

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: Can you please provide us the problem example in codesandbox